# How to remove the "Server" HTTP response header from my Rack app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rack

I am trying to remove the server information from the http response header in my ruby on rails application running on Heroku but I am stuck. Inspecting the response headers gives me:

```
Server:thin 1.5.0 codename Knife
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323331/remove-unnecessary-http-headers-in-my-rails-answers

Comment: @slivu The `Server` header is added by Thin after all the Rack middleware has returned, the question you linked only deals with removing the other headers added by the app. (The other answer suggesting using nginx to strip the headers could work, but not on the Heroku cedar stack.)

Answer (score 2):

This `Server` header is [set by the Thin server](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/v1.4.1/lib/thin/response.rb#L32) when assembling the response. A [recent commit adds the ability to set the `Server` to something else](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/commit/617fccf7f7e1ee93671e8905623852e23fcc296c), but it doesn’t look like you can totally remove it.

One thing you can do is to set the value of the `Thin::VERSION` contsant to `nil`, which results in no `Server` header being sent:

```
Thin.send :remove_const, :SERVER
Thin::SERVER = nil
```

The first line is to avoid the warning that would be generated when altering a constant. Now when Thin tries to set the `Server` header it sees it is `nil` and [skips it](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/v1.4.1/lib/thin/headers.rb#L22-23), so no header is set at all.

Comment: Thanks matt. For some reason this seems a bit hackish to to me. I've just found a solution using Rack middleware (will post about this now) which I prefer to this solution.

Comment: @JonasGrau I agree it’s a bit of a hack, but the code that adds the `Server` header is pretty much “hard coded” into Thin, so I don”t know how else you can control it. I’ll be interested to see your middleware solution – as far as I can tell the header is added after all the middleware has been run and is independent from Rack so I didn’t think you could affect the header from middleware.