# Sinatra: Delete Response Headers

Tags: ruby, http-headers, sinatra, rack

How do I configure [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) to omit the `Date` & `Server` HTTP response headers? I also want to omit the `Content-Type` & `Content-Length` headers when there's no response body. I'm building a REST API server for an iPhone app. My iPhone app doesn't use these headers, and I want to be as efficient as possible.

I tried adding the following after filter, but the headers are still included.

```
after do
  response.headers.delete('Date')
  response.headers.delete('Server')
end
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692701/how-to-remove-the-server-http-response-header-from-my-rack-app

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323331/remove-unnecessary-http-headers-in-my-rails-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A header can be effectively deleted from a Sinatra response by setting it to an empty string. (Not nil, but '') e.g.:

```
get '/myroute/nodate' do

    response.headers['Date']=''

    body="Hello, No Date header in my header!"

end # get
```